# Number of k-tuples of non-negative integers whose sum equals a given integer

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, integer-partitions, multinomial-coefficients, provability

Does the sum over the non-negative integers,

$$
\sum\limits_{ {i_1, \ldots i_k \geq 0:\\\  i_1+\ldots i_k=L }} 1
$$
have a closed expression, where $L$ and $k$ are some integers?

Comment: You're looking at partitions of $L$ into $k$ parts, which is well-studied. Well, it's _slightly_ different, since  you're also allowing zero, but it's not too hard to reduce your situation to the usual case.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Allowing zero _is_ the usual case and the answer is $\binom{L+k-1}L$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: where can I find a proof of this formula?

Comment: you are looking for the [(weak) Compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of L into k parts.  Partitions would appear instead if there was the further restriction $i_1 \le i_2 \le \cdots$

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: Compositions not Partitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ n,k\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\left(=\mathbb{N}\setminus\left\lbrace 0\right\rbrace\right) $.

If $ \left(a_{i_{1},\cdots,i_{k}}\right)_{i_{1},\cdots,i_{k}\geq 0}\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}^{k}} $, then : \begin{aligned}\large\sum_{i_{1}+\cdots +i_{k}=n}{a_{i_{1},\cdots,i_{k}}}=\sum_{0\leq i_{1}\leq\cdots\leq i_{k-1}\leq n}{a_{n-i_{1},i_{1}-i_{2},\cdots ,i_{k-2}-i_{k-1},i_{k-1}}}\end{aligned}

Thus : $$ \sum_{i_{1}+\cdots +i_{k}=n}{1}=\sum_{0\leq i_{1}\leq\cdots\leq i_{k-1}\leq n}{1}=\binom{n+k-1}{k-1} $$

$\textbf{Note :}$ You can prove by induction on $ k $, that $ \sum\limits_{0\leq i_{1}\leq\cdots\leq i_{k}\leq n}{1}=\binom{n+k}{k} $, denoting $ u_{n,k}=\sum\limits_{0\leq i_{1}\leq\cdots\leq i_{k}\leq n}{1} $, we have : $$ u_{n,k}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{u_{i,k-1}} $$